# Edit release template build definition error after RM upgrade

Tags: tfs, msbuild, ms-release-management, tfs-2015

I have upgraded my TFS and RM to 2015 version in a new server. I am using my old RM database(restored the back up manually) with the new RM 2015. I need to modify the release templates to change build definition, servers etc. But when I tried to modify the build definition to newly one, I am getting the error "Cannot connect to TFS. You cannot modify the build definition...". Old build definition is not valid. How I can edit it and select new build definition?

Error screen shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to port over the encryption keys when you migrate to a new RM server.

On the old RM server, run `aspnet_regiis -px "{AB903235-97E6-4B1F-AC8E-0EE51124D84F}" keys.xml -pri`

Then copy `keys.xml` to the new server and run 
`aspnet_regiis -pi "{AB903235-97E6-4B1F-AC8E-0EE51124D84F}" keys.xml`

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/02/need-to-migrating-release-management-server.aspx

Comment: I have done it, but still same error...! I did this step after installing RM server and client. Will it be a problem? I have restarted the RM server after doing this. Will it be enough?

Comment: Restart the Release Management Monitor service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it through a hack in 'Release Management' Database.
TFS connections are stored in [RM].[tbl_TeamFoundationServer] table. I have run an update query against this table and updated invalid tfs connection url to valid url, ie update [RM].[tbl_TeamFoundationServer] set url='http://NewDomain:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection'

After doing this, i am able to edit build definition...!